# Why is there a negative sign in Newton's equation for potential in uniform gravitational fields

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I was doing some homework on uniform gravitational fields, and in deriving the formula for a change in the gravitational potential of an object in the field I produced ΔV = -g*Δr. I think my maths might be correct because rearranging this gives -ΔV/Δr = g, which is the definition of the gravitational field strength (I know its technically a derivative, but I'm assuming that because this is a uniform field this can be ignored...?)

If this equation is correct, what I don't understand is why the potential is proportional to -r, as this implies that the potential will decrease as you increase radius. 
This seems wrong to me, as if I lift an apple to a greater height than it was at before I must do work on it against its weight, and therefore the apple must have gained some potential energy. My equation would imply that because I have increased the height, the potential must have decreased - this is what troubles me, so i am wondering if this is the case, and if so where is my reasoning flawed.
I understand where the negative sign comes from in radial fields - since potential at infinity is zero and moving any object from inside a field to infinity requires you to do work, all points in the field must have a potential less than zero (unless this reasoning is also incorrect...)

If you would like to see how i ended up at this equation, please say so, although I am new to this so my formatting skills are shocking (as you've probably already realised)

Comment: On this site, you can typeset equations using the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) dialect of Latex. Eg, $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta r}$

Comment: You need to define your coordinate system and the direction for positive r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of your equation $-ΔV/Δr = g$ is the gravitational field strength.
If $g$ is positive this means that down is the positive direction as the direction of the gravitational field is downwards.

If one moves up $Δr$ is a negative quantity and so $ΔV$ is a positive quantity ie the potential increases.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of zero gravitational potential is arbitrary.  Physicists have settled on assigning the value of zero at infinity.

Regarding raising an apple in earth's gravitational field, the apple starts with a given negative value of gravitational potential.  As you raise the apple, the gravitational potential becomes less negative.  Because the higher potential is less negative, the apple's gravitational potential has increased, as expected, meaning that for this situation, you are actually interested in the difference in gravitational potential when the apple is displaced upward.